# Data between NSThread

Tags: ios, multithreading, sockets, nsthread

I'll explain my problem.
I need to maintain a tcp connection while my app is running, so I need to have regard to the connection on a background thread. I use the following to connect the socket and works well.

on connection.m

```
 myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(Connect) object:nil];
 [myThread start]; 

-(void)Connect {

        CFReadStreamRef readStream;
        CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
        CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)IP,PORT, &readStream, &writeStream);

        inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
        outputStream =(__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

       [inputStream setDelegate:self];
       [outputStream setDelegate:self];

       [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
       [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
       [inputStream open];
       [outputStream open];
       [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];

}

-(void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {
  //all the code to receive data 
}
```

Now, the connection is working on a different thread to main thread. and I know that if I send something to the main thread I can use this,

```
   performSelectorOnMainThread
```

or

```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ ... do stuff
```

but if what I want is to send something through the outputstream by pressing a button in my view, the function is called,but outputstream is null. I think is because isn't in  the thread where the connection is running.

how I can make that function is executed in the thread where I have the connection?

any help is well appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` ?

Comment: I read about it, but how I can instantiate the thread where the connection is running?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use performSelector:OnThread:?

Comment: I read about it, but how I can instantiate the thread where the connection is running?

Answer (score 0):

Make `NSMutableArray` with `NSLock` to protect it.

Main thread (UI) add items to the end of the list.

TCP thread pool the array to make sure it has something and consumes it.

Each of those two threads must lock the NSLock instance before trying to access the array then unlock it once they are done.

Here is a code snippet that may help you:

```
NSLock* pDataProtector;
NSMutableArray pMessageToBeProcessed;
// init the data variables when the program starts
pDataProtector = [NSLock new];
pMessageToBeProcessed = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// UI code
[pDataProtector lock];
// add item to the array
[pDataProtector unlock];

// in another thread;
while(1)
{
    [pDataProtector lock];
    // if there is an item in the array get it in local var and delete it.
    [pDataProtector unlock];
    //if the local var has a value process it otherwise wait 10 seconds check NSThreads to wait 10 seconds.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering me, but I am newbie in ios. how could I implement that you suggest me?

Comment: Please try to use the code above, it should be placed in 4 different locations in your .h and .m files

Comment: thanks, but to be honest I do not understand how to use it. I do not know if it is right, but I tried to use NSNotificationCenter in the other thread before starting connection. and sending a notification when I need to send the data, it works fine. You think is wrong to use that method?

Comment: Notification Center is very good idea but the trick is to keep the notification name in #define so you can change it easily and document that carefully .